# PHP select data from database

Tags: php, select, mysqli

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "william";
$dbname = "camping";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT fnavn,enavn,epost,tlf FROM knr ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["fnavn"]. " - Name: " . $row["enavn"]. " " . $row["epost"]. "ire: " . $row["tlf"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Tried it, and it doesnt work, anyone who knows why? It's something wrong with the second if statement I think

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Try starting with a sql tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/

Comment: `SELECT (???)  FROM produkt` - You realize you've not selected anything here.

Comment: @RiggsFolly OP set to "ignore" Smokey. Put in an answer instead ;-) You might get a response.

Comment: All yours Ralph. Thanks for the nag on the other question, I did see it. @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome Smokey @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

You would need to join the tables:

```
SELECT * FROM produkt
LEFT JOIN produkttype ON (produkt.ptype = producttype.ptype)
WHERE utleid="No"
```

Comment: How can I then specify it, so I only get no rented product of one kind. For example: I get every no rented cars                                                                               car 1= no rented car 2= no rented car 6=no rented etc

Comment: It's a bit tricky to solve without knowing how your system works. But I think  LEFT JOIN could help you. I'll edit the answer